# xampp unable to start mongo module

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

Hi I downloaded [mongodb msi](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads) and installed version **Windows 64-bit 2008 R2+** by msi format, then i PHP Extension build is TS(Thread Safe) and VC11 [image]

so I download the php mongo driver form [amazon php driver](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html) and include in php/ext folder and add php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11.dll in php.ini file but getting error like below image, help me to solve the issue. thanks to replies in advance
[image]
i searched for the solution but nothing help me.